# How to dynamically import sound files in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

```
  const [soundFile, setSoundFile] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function importFile() {
      const file = await import(
        `../../assets/media/${teamimType}/humash/${teamimType}-parasha.wav`
      );
      setSoundFile(file);
    }
    importFile();
  }, []);
```

the import is working without errors, but when i use it in the sound component -

```
<AudioPlayer
   className="audio-player"
   style={{ direction: 'ltr' }}
   showJumpControls={false}
   autoPlay
   src={soundFile}  // <=====
/>
```

i get the following error:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value**...

after the import, if i log the `file` i get [image: file import log]

probably the import method is wrong but i dont know what to do.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it!

**1.** just use `require` instead of `import`  =>

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const file = require(`../../assets/media/${teamimType}/humash/${teamimType}-parasha.wav`);
    setSoundFile(file);
  }, []);
```

**2.** or stay with `import()` but pass to the Audio component `file.default` (look at the picture in the question) =>

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function importFile() {
      const file = await import(
        `../../assets/media/${teamimType}/humash/${teamimType}-parasha.wav`
      );
      setSoundFile(file.default); // <==========
    }
    importFile();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is this worked?
If yes, please mark solved.
And hope keep in touch with me.

Comment: you can see check icon with gray and click it. if you click it, will turn green color

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use url than import and use it in AudioPlayer.

```
useEffect(() => {
         setSoundFile(`../../assets/media/${teamimType}/humash/${teamimType}-parasha.wav`)
    }
)
...
<AudioPlayer
   className="audio-player"
   style={{ direction: 'ltr' }}
   showJumpControls={false}
   autoPlay
   src={soundFile}
/>
```

In the AudioPlayer component, you can read file by async and process it.

Hope helpful.

Comment: its not working.. the source path in 'production' is different from the 'real' path. you can see it in the picture in my question